# Typeclass with multiple parameters. How to summon an instance having only one parameter?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have been trying to create some sort of a typeclass and encountered problems with implicit resolution.
Basically I want to generate random data and adjust parameters of generation - interval for numbers, length and interval for arrays, etc.
Here is what I've got by now:

```scala
import scala.util.Random

trait PrimitiveGenerator[T <: AnyVal, Bounds] {

  def generate(bounds: Bounds): T

  def generatePossibly(bounds: Bounds): Option[T] = if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.5) None else Some(generate(bounds))

}

object PrimitiveGenerator {
  def apply[A <: AnyVal](implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A, _]) = impl
}

object Generators {

  implicit object IntGenerator extends PrimitiveGenerator[Int, (Int, Int)] {
    override def generate(bounds: (Int, Int) = (0, 1)): Int = Random.nextInt((bounds._2 - bounds._1) + 1) + bounds._1
  }

}


object Test extends App {

  import Generators._
  PrimitiveGenerator[Int].generate((0, 1)) //error is here
}
```

In Intellij Idea this is failing with:

```
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: _$1 where type _$1
  PrimitiveGenerator[Int].generate((0, 1))
```

I have an inkling that using underscore is wrong here, but how could I rewrite it to summon an instance of DataGenerator based only on first type parameter(A). It seems perfectly safe from compilation perspective:
if compiler finds DataGenerator for Int, only in one example, it will use it right away, if it finds several of them with different **Bounds**, just returns an error. This error I could possibly solve adding this parameter to implicit resolution. So what do you think?

**Edit 1**
Thanks to @Dmytro Mitin for solving it!
Looking further, I wanted to make an implementation for Array, so that if we want to summon an instance for an array we should have an instance for Array's parameter type, like this:

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.util.Random

trait PrimitiveGenerator[T] {
  type Bounds
  def generate(bounds: Bounds): T
  def generatePossibly(bounds: Bounds): Option[T] = if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.5) None else Some(generate(bounds))
}

object PrimitiveGenerator {
  type Aux[T, Bounds0] = PrimitiveGenerator[T] { type Bounds = Bounds0 }
  def apply[A](implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A]): Aux[A, impl.Bounds] = impl
}

object Generators {
  implicit object IntGenerator extends PrimitiveGenerator[Int] {
    override type Bounds = (Int, Int)
    override def generate(bounds: (Int, Int) = (0, 1)): Int = Random.nextInt((bounds._2 - bounds._1) + 1) + bounds._1
  }

  implicit def toGenericArrayGenerator[A](implicit generator: PrimitiveGenerator[A],
                                          classTag: ClassTag[A]): PrimitiveGenerator[Array[A]] = new PrimitiveGenerator[Array[A]] {
    override type Bounds = ((Int, Int), generator.Bounds) //It means generate array of length from n to m where elements comply to Bounds of base generator

    override def generate(bounds: Bounds): Array[A] = {
      Array[A]()
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import Generators._
  println(PrimitiveGenerator[Int].generate((0, 42)))
  PrimitiveGenerator[Array[Int]].generate((1 -> 10, 0 -> 42))
}
```

Now I am trying to create array generator dynamically and the Bounds are slightly changed depending on base generator bounds(by plan).
But something went wrong and now I have:

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int), (Int, Int))
 required: impl.Bounds
  PrimitiveGenerator[Array[Int]].generate((1 -> 10, 0 -> 42))
```

How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example try

```
object PrimitiveGenerator {
  def apply[A <: AnyVal] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

  class PartiallyApplied[A <: AnyVal] {
    def apply[B]()(implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A, B]) = impl
  }
}    

object Test extends App {
  import Generators._
  PrimitiveGenerator[Int]().generate((0, 1))
}
```

or

```
object PrimitiveGenerator {
  def generate[A <: AnyVal, B](b: B)(implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A, B]) = impl.generate(b)
}

object Test extends App { 
  import Generators._
  PrimitiveGenerator.generate((0, 1))
}
```

or

```
trait PrimitiveGenerator[T <: AnyVal] {
  type Bounds
  def generate(bounds: Bounds): T
  def generatePossibly(bounds: Bounds): Option[T] = if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.5) None else Some(generate(bounds))
}

object PrimitiveGenerator {
  type Aux[T <: AnyVal, Bounds0] = PrimitiveGenerator[T] { type Bounds = Bounds0 }
  def apply[A <: AnyVal](implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A]): Aux[A, impl.Bounds] = impl
}

object Generators {    
  implicit object IntGenerator extends PrimitiveGenerator[Int] {
    override type Bounds = (Int, Int)
    override def generate(bounds: (Int, Int) = (0, 1)): Int = Random.nextInt((bounds._2 - bounds._1) + 1) + bounds._1
  }    
}

object Test extends App { 
  import Generators._
  PrimitiveGenerator[Int].generate((0, 1))
}
```

or

```
trait PrimitiveGenerator[T <: AnyVal] {
  type Bounds = (T, T)
  def generate(bounds: Bounds): T
  def generatePossibly(bounds: Bounds): Option[T] = if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.5) None else Some(generate(bounds))
}

object PrimitiveGenerator {
  def apply[A <: AnyVal](implicit impl: PrimitiveGenerator[A]): PrimitiveGenerator[A] = impl
}

object Generators {
  implicit object IntGenerator extends PrimitiveGenerator[Int] {
    override def generate(bounds: (Int, Int) = (0, 1)): Int = Random.nextInt((bounds._2 - bounds._1) + 1) + bounds._1
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import Generators._
  PrimitiveGenerator[Int].generate((0, 1))
}
```

Comment: Thanks kindly for the solution you provided! Could you please look at the edited part of this question?

Comment: @D.Silvest Return type of `toGenericArrayGenerator` should be `PrimitiveGenerator.Aux[Array[A], ((Int, Int), generator.Bounds)]` (i.e. refined type) rather than just`PrimitiveGenerator[Array[A]]`.